# How can I change FITID in an ofx file using ofxparse?

Tags: python, ofx

When I debug my code, the changes happen, but when I open the file, nothing was changed.

**Code**

```
from ofxparse import OfxParser
from datetime import datetime as dt

# opening ofx file
with open('/home/jovani/Downloads/ofx.ofx') as file:
    # Parser
    ofx = OfxParser.parse(file)
    #finding transactions
    transactions = ofx.account.statement.transactions
    now = dt.now() # I'll use this id like
    for fitid in transactions: #performing changes and it happens
        fitid_before = fitid.id
        fitid_after = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%f")
        fitid = fitid_after
```

Afterward, nothing was changed in ofx.ofx file.

Comment: Give more explanations of what you did.

Comment: I edited the title of your question to focus on your goal - moving the explanation to the question body.  I also tidied-up a few other things to help readers understand more clearly.

Comment: # ofx file code https://pastebin.com/XJeX9hnW -> I'm attempt to change <FITID> tag with the code

Answer (score 0):

You are asking why the file was not changed.

1. You opened the file for read-only. That is the default with "with open".
2. You did not attempt to write anything to the file.